# Laravel Call to undefined method CreateCommentsTable::integer()

Tags: php, laravel

I Have created a `migration` for my website. but when I run the `php artisan migrate` it gives that error

> Call to undefined method CreateCommentsTable::integer()

**My Migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('post_id');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

the error is on that line of code

> $table->integer('user_id');

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: That error would suggest you've used `$this` instead of `$table`, however, your example doesn't show that...weird.

Comment: @RossWilson i didn't use $this

Comment: I can see that :) All I meant was the error would *suggest* you did which is weird. What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson latest version

Comment: @RossWilson thanks for your help I just autoload the composer and now it works.